# Emailing supervisor after applying for phd to discuss about research problem and funding

Tags: phd, advisor, application, funding, projects

I had contacted a potential supervisor regarding phd position in his lab. He was interested in my profile and advised me to apply for the program. I have applied for the program and informed him about the same. Earlier, We had not discussed about funding and exact research problem. I am curious to know about funding as well as my research problem. I need your opinion on the following

1. What is the appropriate time to discuss about project? Should i wait till I get an offer from admission team to discuss this or while my application is being evaluated can i discuss with my potential supervisor
2. Can i get some help in what should i write in my email when i ask about project and funding?

I thank users in advance for helping me in this regard

Comment: Which country and field?

Comment: Canada and Aerospace propulsion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you are well.

Okay so since you have already applied to the program as per your supervisor - You can reach out to him through email to let him know that you have applied to the program and you will be keeping him in the loop in case of any updates. Along with this you can then ask regarding the research question and its specifics - Make sure the email is not too long though.

Also, and you may find different people with different opinions on this - I would advise not to bring up the funding question in the first email - if he replies to your email you will be sending after admission submission - only after that you can go for the funding question.

Saying this because certain times supervisors do not have funding readily available and are always looking for students that are self-funding because that is in their favor ofcourse.

Hope it helps - Let me know if you need help with something.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!this will help